# Send welcome email when creating an order from admin

Tags: admin, customer-account

I am using Magento 1.8 and finding that when I place an order from admin for a new customer, they don't receive the welcome email, only the order email. What this means is that they don't receive their username and password.

This is quite important as if they purchase a PDF then they really do need it.

Should this be happening automatically, or is a there a way so that they do receive it?

Answer (score 2):

Ya it doesn't do that by default, but instead of fiddling with code to do that there are two workarounds.

1- Create the customer before creating the order:
Go to Customers->Manage Customer then click add new customer, on this page add the necessary info and tick the "send welcome email" then save.

2- Create the order as you normally would then go to the customer's page after creating the order, fill the needed info and tick "send welcome email" then save.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, as it is also creating the account as creating the order, would it not be possible to just trigger the correct email to go off with a small code change?

Comment: Don't know exactly what changes would need to be done to trigger it automatically and don't how simple it would be but you will probably also need automatically generate the password too.

Comment: Just to clarify, an account is being created. The customer can go to the login page and request forgotten password.

Comment: Ok, well unfortunately i  don't have enough time to fully research this now, but if you look at file /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php. You can find the method sendNewAccountEmail(), if you can find a way to integrate this method into the account creating process it might work